# How do you change the 'master' branch of a cloned Git repo to point to your own remote?

Tags: git, git-clone

I cloned a third-party Github repo, made my own changes and pushed to my own remote I need to use from different locations, by creating my own bare remote repository and pushing my changes to it - basically like this:

```
git init --bare ~/repos/customized.git
git remote add customized myname@host:/home/myname/repos/customized.git
git push --all customized
git remote rename origin upstream
```

Executing `git branch -a` produces this output:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/rca_customized/master
  remotes/upstream/HEAD -> upstream/master
  remotes/upstream/master
```

What I want now is to make the master branch refer to my `customized` repo so that `git push` automatically pushes to the `customized` which I suspect should result in `git branch -a` producing the output below.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/upstream/master
  remotes/customized/HEAD -> customized/master
  remotes/customized/master
```

What I am not sure is whether after accomplishing what I want on the local repo and pushing to 'customized', cloning `customized` from other locations will result in the output of `git branch -a` showing `origin` where it says `customized` on the initial location. I'd rather it said `customized` rather than `origin`, but there may be good reason to stick to the origin convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the tracking remote branch for a local branch using `--set-upstream-to`.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch --set-upstream-to customized/master
```

Get further info about remote branches in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/ch3-5.html).

`origin` is just the default remote name that git assigns to the repository you cloned from. Remote names are just aliases for URLs and are local to each repository. So you simply have no way to set up a remote to instruct its clones to set up a specific name, other than `origin`, for the remote reference. If you want to use a different name you have to manually rename it after cloning.